# Does the F-22 (or any other stealth aircraft) carry chaff?

Tags: military, radar, stealth, f-22

Considering it is nearly undetectable on radar, it seems like it wouldn't have to worry about radar guided missiles; in addition to this it is sure to have sophisticated jamming capabilities. So why carry chaff? Just weight.

Comment: wikipedia says it carries flares for IR guided missiles

Comment: @ratchetfreak Flares =/= chaff

Comment: my point exactly.

Comment: Combat (particularly fighter) aircraft typically carry both chaff & flares. They aren't mutually exclusive. Wikipedia isn't the most credible source for the newest 5th generation stealth fighter either haha.

Comment: Chaff doesn't weighs much; the lighter it is, the longer it stays in the air. The F-22's payload is several tons.

Comment: Wouldn't the chaff/flare dispensers present a radio frequency signature management problem, resulting in the deletion of them from the design?

Comment: @brinnb I imagine an alternate delivery system could be devised with a minimal radar cross section - all that's really needed is a hole through which the flare (or chaff) could be expelled, perhaps by compressed air...

Comment: You raised a really good point putting "nearly" in your question. The techniques evolves, it is reasonnable to assume that stealth today is not the same as stealth in few decades. Moreover, detection capabilities differ depending on the ennemy. Thus wise to carry state-of-the-art jamming device AND chaff. As pointed out by @ChrisW carrying chaff is not such a constraint.

Comment: @ManuH the chaff itself isn't that heavy, but combine it with the equipment needed to launch it, the controls in the cockpit, the wiring, electrical circuits, probably automated systems as well integrated with the threat detection devices, it all adds up both in bulk and weight.

Comment: If nation A has top-secret stealth aircraft then surely it should assume the worst-case scenario, which is that nation B has a top-secret way of defeating their stealthiness. Because if nation B did have that then it would make every effort to keep it secret.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the capability to carry and the decision, or need, to carry are different things.  I can't answer for the new generation, but older models the dispensing system was capable of handling cartridges with either chaff or flares. (cartridges were interchangeable) The actual load carried, (or mix of loads) was decided based on the threat.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It certainly seems so.

Stealth aircraft are not *invisible* to radar, only *less* visible.  Under certain conditions the adversary will be able to get a radar lock:

- At close distance
- With very high (focused) radar energy
- At certain angles of incidence

Given these risks and the low weight of chaff, it wouldn't be be wise to not carry it.

One source that claims the F-22 carries chaff: http://science.howstuffworks.com/f-22-raptor8.htm

> It releases **flares** to confuse heat seekers and sends out **chaff**, small pieces of reflective material, to disperse radar waves and confuse a radar-guided missile's tracking system.

It's even been used in the field, [according to The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/checkpoint/wp/2017/12/14/u-s-f-22s-fired-warning-flares-at-russian-planes-in-close-call-over-syria-pentagon-says/?utm_term=.3854b6c87a9e):

> the [F-22s] shot flares and even chaff — clouds of metal meant to confuse radar systems but possibly used in this case as an additional visual warning.

Comment: That said I did read or here somewhere (not sure where, but it was reliable-sounding source) that B-2 does *not* have chaff.

Comment: Good point. Keep in mind that chaff and jamming work together. Radar is beaten when the noise exceed the real signal. If you get a unjammed bounce off the chaff and a jammed bounce off a stealthy F22, the radar is quite likely going to give up.

Comment: @JanHudec [This B-2 documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2bihncjy0U) mentions that the B-2 does not have chaff nor flares.

Comment: @florisla - There are strategic, technological and tactical reasons for this. The biggest reason is that the B-2 doesn't maneuver very well, and chaff/flares really only work in combination with high-G maneuvering to cause the missile to fall behind the aircraft's flight path. The B-2 was also designed to penetrate USSR territory unseen and launch nuclear cruise missiles at strategic targets. In that doomsday scenario, surviving to launch is the only goal; once the bomber's empty it might as well kamikaze, as its home base and the entire chain of command will all be gone before it returns.

Comment: The F-22, while stealthy, is also designed to maneuver and dogfight, and so the added weight and bulk of the chaff/flare dispenser is considered necessary to help keep a $185 million air superiority fighter in the air fighting for superiority, instead of falling to the ground in pieces.

Comment: I can't validate beyond a personal anecdote, but the F-22 carries a chaff/flare system - I know this, because I've touched a prototype launcher. Back in high school (mid-90s), my school worked with Lockheed Martin via US First. One of the engineers we were working with had it on his desk. It was a surprisingly small device.

Comment: Also, jet fighters are designed to be in service for decades. One could assume detection technology might improve during its lifespan.

Comment: @keithS I cannot speak to todays war plans, but back in the 1980's SAC had two scenarios, a surprise attack and couple of days build up to open war. For the surprise attack the aircraft we kept on alert could be off the gourd in a bout 5 minutes.. This was often practiced. For the couple of days build up, we would arm every plane then send out teams to set up alternate bases at civilian airport, old military bases and even log stretches' of the interstate. This so we could recover and rearm returning planes for a follow on strike. This usually only minimally practiced.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The F-22 carries a pair of AN/ALE-52 countermeasures dispensers capable of carrying combinations of chaff and flare cartridges.  The dispensers are located on the underside of the fuselage aft of the main weapons bay.  Similar to the gun muzzle, the dispensers are covered by a pair of fast acting fairing doors, which snap shut quickly after use to minimize disruptions in the radar cross section of the aircraft during use.